# Using se with the first person singular conjugation

Tags: gramática

One of the questions on this site asks how to express in Spanish a situation where you're having, say, a shower and the faucet suddenly runs dry. The only answer posted suggested this:

> Se corto el agua.

Is it common to use `se` with a verb conjugated in the first person as in the example above? If so, what's the grammar behind such usage? I only ever understood that reflexive verbs take `me` when used in the `yo` form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the phrase you cite is missing an accent mark. The correct one would be:

> Se cort**ó** el agua

So the verb is in third person singular of the simple past tense, as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common. If you already understand `me` for the first person, `se` is for the third. 
i.e It is use for things that happen to inanimate objects like in this example and yours.

> Se dañó el carro = the car broke.

Also as reflexive for the third person

> Juan se entrena para la carrera = Juan trains (himself) for the race
>
> Juan se está entrenando para la carrera = Juan is training for the
>   race.

One more way to say your example using both `se` and `me` could be

> Se me cortó el agua

which means `The water run dry on me.` or `The water went off on me`

And by the way...don't get confused with the conjugation of the verb "`saber`" in sentences like

> "I know = yo se"

I hope this helps.

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

### Se cortó el agua

Refers to the flow of water mains have been cut.

**So it's like saying:**

> El flujo del agua se cortó.

It is the tilde(Accent) sets the third person of the singular, of the first prerson.

> Yo **corto** pan. - *I cut bread.*
>
> Pepita se **cortó** el pelo. - *Pepita got a haircut.*

"se" can be used if you use "usted" too.

> Usted se **cortó** el dedo sólito.

**"Usted"** is an third person of singular, but it means **"tú"** a degree of respect, at least in the correct use of language, as in many countries **"Usted"** not charge any sense of respect.

---

How **"Usted"** it possible that this is the third person singular and second at the same time?

Because it is used as a second person instead of **"tú"**, but it really is the third person, as **"usted"** means **"vuestred"** - **"Vuestra merced"** It is similar to the English word "your self" what does it mean **"tú y tu persona"** (Your body and mind, nonsense respect of the Middle Ages)...

---

**Usted** was used to speak with a degree of respect for people without titles like "**su santidad**", "**su excelencia**" "**su magnificencia**" was descortez mention the other person directly saying "**tú**, or "**vos**", it was disrespectful.

---